# gspread Python How to set the value of a checkbox

Tags: python, checkbox, gspread

I'm using python to manipulate a gsheet and I can't seem to find a straight forward answer to this question. From what I can tell, it requires the use of DataValidationRule and set_data_validation_rule, but I'm in over my head in this and was wondering if some of you nice people wouldn't mind setting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use the update method with a string of the words `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`, but all I needed to do was pass it the boolean value of `True` or `False`.

```
sheet.update(cell, True or False)
```